# Retrieve linked entities with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following EF Code First classes:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class RequestLinked
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Request")]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("RequestRelated")]
    public int RequestRelatedID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Request RequestRelated { get; set; }
}
```

I need to establish links between multiple requests.

For example: let's say I have `Request` IDs 1, 2, 3. Next I define links between 1-2 and 1-3 like below:

```
new RequestLinked { RequestID = 1, RequestRelatedID = 2 } <-- A    
new RequestLinked { RequestID = 1, RequestRelatedID = 3 } <-- B
```

Based on the entities above, I would like to be able to see related requests for a specific request.

So for example:

- for request 1: linked to 2 & 3
- for request 2: linked to 1 & 3
- for request 3: linked to 1 & 2

Any Idea how to get these links with LINQ ?

---

UPDATE

I'll try to be clear below:

Let's say we search linked requests for ID 3. What must be retrieved?

- We found that ID 3 is linked to ID 1 (see entry A)
- (Now we need to search if ID 1 has other linked elements)
- And we found ID 1 is linked to ID 2 (see entry B)
- ==> Return 1 & 2